# Open specific tags in xml

Tags: php, xml

I want to open clildren of body, I mean OriginCurrency. The only thing I can, is to open just the first tag OriginCurrency.

I have the following code:

```
<body>
    <OrigCurrency val="Euro">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <Rate currency="USD">1.3764</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CHF">1.2079</Rate>
            <Rate currency="GBP">0.8731</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency>
    <OrigCurrency val="USD">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <currency>JPY</currency>
            <rate>70.0554</rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency> 
    <OrigCurrency val="CHF">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <Rate currency="USD">1.1379</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency>
    <OrigCurrency val="GBP">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <Rate currency="CAD">1.5648</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency>
</body>
```

Here is the php code:

```
?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('curs.xml')or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$eurtousd = $xml->OrigCurrency->Cube->Rate[0]; //works
$eurtochf = $xml->OrigCurrency->Cube->Rate[1]; //works
$eurtogbp = $xml->OrigCurrency->Cube->Rate[2]; //works

$usdtojpy = $xml->OrigCurrency[1]->Cube->Rate; //doesn't work
>?
```

If I try with OrigCurrency[1], it doesnt work.
And, if is there a way to show it with the val like OrigCurrency['USD'], just to know which one is selected, because there may be like one hundred tags and is not a professional way to count one hundred tags to show the one you want. I want help with that. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to use `USD` for instance, iterate `OrigCurrency` tag and find out which one contains `val="USD"`. You could also build an array with keys as currency and value as its rate. I would be easier to retrieve later for other currencies as well.

Comment: The idea is great but as a newbie, I need an example...

Comment: Please post the original xml, as the one above doesn't work with `simplexml_load_file`. Is this BNR currency xml?

Comment: Yes but it is modified by me. It is the hole code I have posted above.

Comment: I'm doing it right now. Wait for it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56166/discussion-between-mariusb-and-machineaddict).

Comment: From a quick glance your `$xml->OrigCurrency[1]` should work. have you double-checked you don't have mistake somewhere else?

Comment: it works just with OrigCurrency[0]

Comment: @MariusB: As commented, this perfectly works: https://eval.in/166309

Comment: yes. i guess it works this way but i already choose  the way with foreach, looks more simple. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A working code:

```
<?php

$xml = '<body>
    <OrigCurrency val="Euro">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <Rate currency="USD">1.3764</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CHF">1.2079</Rate>
            <Rate currency="GBP">0.8731</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency>
    <OrigCurrency val="USD">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <currency>JPY</currency>
            <rate>70.0554</rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency> 
    <OrigCurrency val="CHF">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <Rate currency="USD">1.1379</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency>
    <OrigCurrency val="GBP">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <Rate currency="CAD">1.5648</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency>
</body>';

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->xmlStandalone = false;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$OrigCurrency = $dom->getElementsByTagName('OrigCurrency');

$new_array = array();
foreach ($OrigCurrency as $row) {

    // OrigCurrency node
    $currency = $row->getAttribute('val');

    // Cube node
    $cube_node = $row->getElementsByTagName('Cube')->item(0);
    $date = $cube_node->getAttribute('date');

    // currency node
    $currency_node = $cube_node->getElementsByTagName('currency');

    $rates = array();
    if ($currency_node->length > 0) { // is currency + rate
        $rate_node = $cube_node->getElementsByTagName('rate');
        $rates[$currency_node->item(0)->nodeValue] = $rate_node->item(0)->nodeValue;
    } else { // is Rate and currency attribute
        $rate_nodes = $cube_node->getElementsByTagName('Rate');
        foreach ($rate_nodes as $row2) {
            $rate_currency = $row2->getAttribute('currency');
            $rate_value = $row2->nodeValue;
            $rates[$rate_currency] = $rate_value;
        }
    }

    $new_array[$currency][$date] = $rates;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Euro] => Array
        (
            [2014-06-20] => Array
                (
                    [USD] => 1.3764
                    [CHF] => 1.2079
                    [GBP] => 0.8731
                )

        )

    [USD] => Array
        (
            [2014-06-20] => Array
                (
                    [JPY] => 70.0554
                )

        )

    [CHF] => Array
        (
            [2014-06-20] => Array
                (
                    [USD] => 1.1379
                )

        )

    [GBP] => Array
        (
            [2014-06-20] => Array
                (
                    [CAD] => 1.5648
                )

        )

)
```

`$new_array` variable contains all you need. This is more "professional" way of getting it, as it is dinamic.

Comment: I aprove this code but it is very difficult to me to show each value because I do math with these values. here is a piece of code that I calculate with the values:
if($cur1=="EUR" AND $cur2=="USD")
 {
  echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";
  echo "<center>" . (float)$amount*(float)$eurtousd . "</center>";
 }

Comment: Your coding is ambiguous. You should build a currency class that can convert any currency in any currency, this way you remove that ugly code. Not to mention that this `(float)$amount*(float)$eurtousd` doesn't show very nice sometimes, you need also to format it. Example of class http://pastebin.com/hdx1jxSm

Comment: I know it is ambiguous. for the moment I am newbie, i guess i must do it my way. thank you for the code but it is hard to me a little

Comment: No problem. We've all been there. One advice: read articles (like tutsplus) and test them out. You will find new ways of programming which will shape your skills.

Comment: how could I create something like this in your like you sent: pastebin.com/hdx1jxSm ? instead of using "if" and "for" statements?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to point it to JPY, you can also do foreach:

```
$xml_string = '<body> <OrigCurrency val="Euro"> <Cube date="2014-06-20"> <Rate currency="USD">1.3764</Rate> <Rate currency="CHF">1.2079</Rate> <Rate currency="GBP">0.8731</Rate> </Cube> </OrigCurrency> <OrigCurrency val="USD"> <Cube date="2014-06-20"> <currency>JPY</currency> <rate>70.0554</rate> </Cube> </OrigCurrency> <OrigCurrency val="CHF"> <Cube date="2014-06-20"> <Rate currency="USD">1.1379</Rate> </Cube> </OrigCurrency> <OrigCurrency val="GBP"> <Cube date="2014-06-20"> <Rate currency="CAD">1.5648</Rate> </Cube> </OrigCurrency></body>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string); // or load file in your case
foreach($xml->OrigCurrency as $currency) {
    $val = $currency->attributes();
    if($val['val'] == 'USD') {
        $usdtojpy =  $currency->Cube->rate; 
    }
}

echo $usdtojpy; // 70.0554
```

Comment: @MariusB `looks like it doesn't work`? wow! you have to be more specfic than that. check my edit and try it again

Comment: I tried to change the rate to Rate here: $usdtojpy =  $currency->Cube->rate; why with  the capital is not working, because in the xml file it is with capital letter Rate?!

Comment: @MariusB since PHP is case sensitive, look at the node on `val="USD"`, its in small caps `<rate>`, the others are `<Rate>`